# PHPSpreadsheet Fails to Save Line Chart Loaded From Template (Locked by 'another user')

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am running into a problem where phpspreadsheet will not write out a line chart from an xlsx file I'm using as a template.

I get two error messages when opening the spreadsheet:

> We found a problem with some content in 'Hello World.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?  If you trust the source of the workbook, click Yes

> Hello World.xlsx is locked for editing
>
> by 'another user'
>
> Open 'Read-Only' or click 'Notify' to open read-only and receive notification when the document is no longer in use.

```
<?php
// ... snip

$reader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$reader->setIncludeCharts(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

// ... snip

// populate chart data
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Ratios');

// reverse order, so populate "backwards"
for($endingRow = 14; ($endingRow > 1) && ($row = $last13Ratios->nextRecord()); $endingRow--) {
  $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$endingRow, $row->date);
  $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$endingRow, $row->percent60/100);
  $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$endingRow, $row->percent90/100);
  $helper->log(print_r($row));
}

// ... snip

$writer = new XlsxWriter($spreadsheet);
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$callStartTime = microtime(true);
$writer->save($saveFileName);
$helper->logWrite($writer, $saveFileName, $callStartTime);
$spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
die();
```

If I put fake data in the template, it appears to work.  But I don't want fake data, just in case something goes haywire.  Better to have no information than wrong information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is to put a space `'`  in the upper left cell of the section being used for data in the template.

Note that the data type appears to make a difference, also:  a date instead of a string will fail.

Be sure to use the single quote mark to designate it as a string, otherwise excel will ignore the space when you save it.